# Heteroscedasticity and simple linear regression

Tags: regression, heteroscedasticity

I have 2 continuous variables and I want to conduct a simple linear regression, 1 DV and 1 IV. There is a moderate correlation between them. However, I suspect there may be some heteroscedasticity and I cannot run a regression in SPSS. Also I am not sure if my residual scatter plot really shows a triangle / heteroscedasticity. I have 75 participants. Here is my scatter plot. Any suggestions?

[image]

Comment: I don't really see a triangle here. What makes you think you have heteroscedasticity? The predicted values seem to come in regular intervals / at discrete locations, do you know why that is? Were the original data grouped at fixed intervals on X?

Comment: So as i have no heteroscasticity, cant i make linear regression?

Comment: Note that the existence of Heteroscedacity will not effect the coefficient estimates in the regression but rather only the standard errors of the coefficients.  So your estimates from a linear regression will be the same regardless of adjustment.  I suppose I can see a "football" like shape to the residual plot which can be a mark of heteroscedacity in certain data.  I am not familiar with SPSS but most statistical packages offer a "robust" option in regression which adjusts for heteroscedacity in standard error.

Comment: @gung has it right: heteroscedasticity. Show us the scatter plot too, but there is little to worry about in that plot in my view.

Comment: Thanks a lot, so it seems i accomplished all assumptions for linear regression. This site is awesome!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From your plot, I don't think there is problematic heteroscedasticity.  I think you are OK to run a simple linear regression here.